# Событие выделения текста в TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter, entry

Я пишу GUI с использованием TKinter. И столкнулся с проблемой, на которую я не нашел решения:

В моём интерфейсе есть поле для ввода (`Entry`). Пользователь вводит в него некую информацию. Мне нужно что-бы пользователь **не мог выделить текст** в этом поле. Это важно.

Я пробовал решить эту проблему тем, что создавал поток с помощью `Threading`, и в бесконечном цикле очищал выделение с помощью `selection_clear()`. Но сомневаюсь что это хорошее решение. Может есть способ отслеживать событие выделения текста в `Entry`?

Comment: посмотрите тут. что-то похожее - https://coderoad.ru/26208695/Как-отключить-выделение-текста-в-программе-Python-Tk

Comment: @splash58 Спасибо. Но там все решения не дают пользователю вводить текст. А мне нужно что-бы пользователь мог вводить текст, но при этом не мог его выделять

Comment: События выделения я не нашел. Как вариант, отлавливать события отпускания кнопки мыши и клавиш клавиатуры, проверять выделение, если оно есть - очищать.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Попробую.

Comment: В Tcl/Tk я бы это сделан на уровне биндов или перехватил бы саму команду "selection". Но там вообще довольно много событий где происходит выделение (tk::EntryMouseSelect, tk::EntryKeySelect). Вот дефолтные биндинги Entry - https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/main/library/entry.tcl

Comment: @GrAnd можно на примере хотя бы с одним биндом, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю есть ли нативный способ сделать это кодом на Питоне... Но т.к. в tkinter доступен интерпретатор Tcl/Tk, то через Tcl можно перехватить *(переопределить)* процедуру работы с созданным виджетом (в Tcl каждый виджет создаёт собственную команду (имеющую такое же имя как и сам виджет) для управления собой). А в этой процедуре просто ничего не делать, если её вызвали с параметрами `selection range` (установка выделения), а для остальных вариантов вызова передавать управление старой процедуре. Эта *блокировка* будет работать даже с дефолтными биндингами, т.к. они тоже работают с виджетом через использование этой процедуры.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def set_entry_no_select(root, entry):
    root.eval(f"""
        # Yeah, this is Tcl code inside Python :)
        rename {entry} {entry}_orig
        proc {entry} args {{
            if {{[string match {{se*}}    [lindex $args 0]] && 
                 [string match {{[atr]*}} [lindex $args 1]]}} {{
                # disable "selection adjust|to|range" sub-commands
                return
            }}
            tailcall {entry}_orig {{*}}$args
        }}
    """)

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.StringVar(root, "Entry Entry Entry") 
entry = tk.Entry(textvariable=text)
set_entry_no_select(root, entry)
entry.pack()

text2 = tk.StringVar(root, "TtkEntry TtkEntry TtkEntry") 
entry2 = ttk.Entry(textvariable=text2)
set_entry_no_select(root, entry2)
entry2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ваши труды! Работает. Однако с помощью shift текст все еще можно выделить. Можете пожалуйста исправить?

Comment: Хм... У `ttk.Entry` - не выделяет. У обычного - выделяет.

Comment: Точно! Еще раз большое спасибо! Теперь все работает.

Comment: @Никита У простого Entry ещё парочку `selection` под-команд (кроме `range`) надо было заблокировать - `adjust` и `to`. Добавил и их блокировку тоже.

Comment: Работает, спасибо.